# Update to Joomla 3.3.3 from 3.3.1 failed, could not open CONTRIBUTING.md

Tags: joomla, upgrade, failed-installation

I tried to update my Joomla 3.3.1 installation to 3.3.3 just now but my browser immediately gave the alert that CONTRBUTING.md could not be opened. It should be in the root folder of my installation, but it is not there. Moreover, when I download a new full package from Joomla there isn't a CONTRIBUTING.md either.
How can I solve this? I have never deleted CONTRBUTING.md so I don't know why it is gone.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why it would require that file however it's pretty easy to re create. Do you have shell access to your server? If not create a file called CONTRIBUTING.MD and load it to the server via FTP or vim into the file via shell and insert the following copy:

```
Contributing to the Joomla! CMS
===============
All contributions are welcome to be submitted for review for inclusion in the Joomla! CMS, but before they will be accepted, we ask that you follow these simple steps:

1) Open an item on the Joomlacode tracker in the appropriate area.
* CMS Bug Reports: http://joomlacode.org/gf/project/joomla/tracker/?action=TrackerItemBrowse&tracker_id=8103
* CMS Feature Requests: http://joomlacode.org/gf/project/joomla/tracker/?action=TrackerItemBrowse&tracker_id=8549

2) Follow the [Joomla! Coding Standards](http://joomla.github.io/coding-standards)!

3) After submitting the item to the Joomlacode tracker, add a link to the Joomlacode tracker item and the GitHub issue or pull request.

Please be patient as not all items will be tested immediately (remember, all bug testing for the Joomla! CMS is done by volunteers) and be receptive to feedback about your code.

#### Branches
Pull Requests should usually be made for the `staging` branch as this contains the most recent version of the code.
There are other branches available which serve specific purposes.

| Branch | Purpose |
| ------ | ------- |
| staging | Current codebase. |
| master | Each commit made to staging gets tested if it passes unit tests and codestyle rules and then merged into master. This is done automatically. |
| 2.5.x | Branch for the Joomla 2.5.x series. Currently in maintenance mode with EOL end of 2014. No new features are accepted here. |
| 3.2.x | Branch for the Joomla 3.2.x series. Currently in security mode with EOL Oct 2014. Only security issues are fixed. |
| 3.4-dev | Branch for the next minor Joomla version. New backward compatible features go into this branch. Commits to staging will be applied to this branch as well. |
```

Save that, make sure the file had the normal permissions and you should be all set. Note you need this to be in the root or base directory where Joomla! is installed.

Comment: Thanks that resoled that issue. Unfortunately now I get a 'invalid login' alert...

Comment: After changing all the files in the root to 777, the invalid login has disappeared but it asked the same way as above for README.md, LICENSE.txt and now htaccess.txt. Can't I install it in a different way than using the built in update system?

Comment: @user2976720 - The file that has been provided for you here has nothing to do with an invalid login. This file is simply text and doesn't server any functionality purpose. Do **not** change anything to 777. All folder must be 755 and files should be 644

Comment: @Lodder I changed it back already but since it's only in development it wouldn't be that important? Do you have any idea how I can solve my problem?

Comment: Now try upgrading again